# How to order event in multiple streams in one single Epser Engine

Tags: java, esper

Currently I am using the [Esper](http://esper.codehaus.org/) event processor. The situation is as follows:

There is one server receiving multiple messages from clients, those messages are inserted into a stream. Currently there are two types of streams, called **str1, str2**, both contain different event types. In order to align the messages coming from the different clients, I am in search of an aligning mechanism.

The package of one eventtype (**type1**) contains absolute timing information, variable called **globaltime**. Now the challenge is to order the events of the different clients of **type1**, and accordingly the events of **type2** can be ordered by information coming from the order of  type1 events.

My first intuition is to take a time window of **x** seconds and use *ORDER BY* Clause. But then how do I order the **type2** events based on ordering of events of **type1**.

I hope this explanation is clear enough to throw some suggestions or hints.

Thnx in advance.

Grtz
Mv2k

Comment: Instead of ordering with esper, I ordered the events before they entered the stream.

Answer (score 0):

there is a time order window in Esper that would seem to do the job